# javafx application :How to call a method in a class that already running in jvm to update static field from another class

Tags: javafx-8

i have two classes in javafx application when i run my first class with static label in it then it calls a second class which executes some code and it must update the static label in the first class.

MAIN CLASS:

```
class main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
first f=new first();
f.render();

}
}
```

first class :

```
class first
{
public static Label msg;
first()
{
msg=new Label();
}
void render()
{
second s=new second();
s.login();
}

void setmsg(String s)
{
msg.setText(s);
}

}
```

SECOND CLASS:

```
public class second
{
void login()
{
//some login code
first f=new first();
f.setmsg("some text");
}
}
```

if i call f.setmsg() method it must call the already running first class to set the message in the label.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clearify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the Moment you have two instances of class `first`. You have to pass it on to your `second`-class constructor.

Change your Code to something like this:

```
class first {
    public static Label msg;
    first() {
        msg=new Label();
    }

    void render(){
        second s=new second(this);
        s.login();
    }

    void setmsg(String s){
        msg.setText(s);
    }
}


public class second {
    private first firstClass = null;

    second(first theFirstClassInstance){
        this.firstClass = theFirstClassInstance;
    }

    void login() {
        //some login code
        firstClass.setmsg("some text");
    }
}

public class third{
    private first firstClass = null;

    third(first theFirstClassInstance){
        this.firstClass = theFirstClassInstance;
    }

    void login() {
        //some login code
        firstClass.setmsg("some text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very MUCH , again i having one doubt that first class calls second class , then second class calls third one , finally third class to access the first class ?.. pls replay thanks.

Comment: Just pass the constructed `first` class variable to the constructor of `third` class. See my updated answer. And welcome to S.O.

Comment: i had another doubt that : if i am calling class1 -> class2 -> class3 -> class1 , then so i have to pass the class1 object reference to all the classes isnt ?